# What is the best way to create a variable SetDirectory folder (according to the computer i use)

Tags: export

I use Mathematica on a linux mint desktop pc and on my notebook.
I would like to create a template notebook for all my work that Exports or saves (the .nb or other files) in my google drive folder.
The google drive folder is in different paths on each computer.
I am trying to find a variable that is computer dependent so that there is a Conditional Expression that selects it.
Something like this?

```
SetDirectory = Switch[PCVariable,LinuxMint,"/users/me/linuxboxgdrive",MacOSX,"users/me/macosxgdrive"]
```

Thanks in advance!

J.

Comment: You can use `$MachineName`, but I don't know if I got your problem right.

Comment: Assuming you have manually saved the file once in your google drive folder (on any platform), subsequent calls to `NotebookDirectory` will give the correct path when the file is loaded on any of your systems.

Comment: I used to have the same problem, but then standardized on putting the shared directory at "~/Shared/Mathematica", which could be retrieved with FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Shared", "Mathematica"}] on all systems (Windows, Un*x, and Mac). This basic approach, with appropriate modifications to directory names, may solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution but I have run into a similar problem.  You can save a file on the google drive, lets say its G://newTextFile.txt

```
list = {"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"};
drive = Table[FileExistsQ[i <> ":\\newTextFile.txt"], {i,list}];
number = Flatten@Position[drive, True];
driveletter = ToString@list[[number[[1]]]];
```

Then you can use it with FileNameJoin.  Or you can use FindFile.